# Basic Registration Page - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am a complete beginner with iOS (started yesterday). I am trying too create a simple register page with text boxes and labels.

I have done this with a UITable view - which looks pretty decent for a first attempt.

However, I am facing an issue where the bottom values on my form are hidden by the keyboard. Even after I changed the Return Key to next (i assume this should send the cursor and the focus to the next column?)

Can someone offer some advise on how this can be solved? The below screen shot shows phone number field is hidden and my submit button :(

[image]

Comment: set UITableView's Frame for particular Textfields. like `if (textfield== email){ tableview.frame = CGRectMake(0, -100, 320, 460);}` this may help you

Comment: let me highlight the _AppStore Review Guideline_ section **17. Privacy**, especially _"17.2 Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView` Instead of `UITableview` in your project.

download class of `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView` [download](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) and add your project.

in your .h file add

```
#import "TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.h"
```

define propery of tableview

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView *TableViewRate;
```

and also change class of `UITableView` to `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView` as below image.

[image]

When you click on textfiled its auto set it frame according to Keyborad. so each textfield is shown when update.

Comment: thanks very much for the help - seems a bit of a hassle to have to do that really though! why apple don't provide this is beyond me