# make iOS page scrollable when keyboard is enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scroll, keyboard

I have an iOS page for register and I want to make it scrollable if the keyboard is enabled, because at the moment I can't scroll to the register button at the end of the page and the keyboard covert the button.

Is there any smart solution?

Comment: What iOS page? You mean to say `UIView` or it is `html` page in `UIWebView`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157161/basic-registration-page-ios/25157397#25157397

Comment: Are there any Swift examples?

Answer (score 1):

For solving of you're problem are quite a lot of solutions. From using `UIScrolView` to changing frame or constrain.

If you would like to use `UIScrolView` you should insert you register form `UIView` to `UIScrolView` and set content size.

Code sniper how to handle keyboard and scrollview.

First of all you should know when keyboard is shown and hide. Use notifications for that :

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}
```

After that use methods (`keyboardWasShown` and `keyboardWillBeHidden`) of notifications to change `contentInsets`.

Example of changing of the `contentInsets` :

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Finally solution is depends from you're choice you can change frame or constrain as well like `UIScrolView` parameters.